# pyspark read csv file multiLine option not working for records which has newline spark2.3 and spark2.2

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the dat file using pyspark csv reader and it contains newline character ("\n") as part of the data. Spark is unable to read this file as single column, rather treating it as new row. 
I tried using the "multiLine" option while reading , but still its not working.

`spark.read.csv(file_path, schema=schema, sep=delimiter,multiLine=True)`

Data is something like this. Here $ is CRLF for newline shown in vim.

`name,test,12345,$
$
,desc$
name2,test2,12345,$
$
,desc2$`

So pyspark is treating desc as next record.

How to read such data in pyspark . 
Tried this in both spark2.2 and spark2.3 versions.

Comment: You should confirm the pattern in the data and use wholeTextFile api to read the file and parse data to form the dataframe you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own hadoop Custom Record Reader and was able to read it by invoking the api .

`spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(file_path,'com.test.multi.reader.CustomFileFormat','org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable','org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',conf=conf)`

And in the Custom Record Reader implemented the logic to handle the newline characters encountered .